QuantLib - American put with discrete dividend - inverse fails
I'm comparing QL and IBKR analytics (tickOptionComputation() message) for American options with a single dividend,

data collected 9/13/2024;
SPY 20240920 puts and calls;
1.76 USD dividend for SPY shares with ex-date 9/20/2024.

One sanity check is that option value and implied volatility are (at least approximately numerically) invertible.  I expect:
$$\begin{aligned}
\textrm{option-value} &= f\left(\textrm{implied-volatility}\right) \\
\textrm{implied-volatility} &= f^{-1}\left(\textrm{option-value}\right) \\
\textrm{option-value} &\approx f\left(f^{-1}\left(\textrm{option-value}\right)\right)
\end{aligned}$$
For SPY calls, this approximation roughly holds.  However, for SPY puts, the discrepancy between input and output option value is too large.  See for instance the SPY 20240920 559 P difference (bottom right value) in output below.
Things are likely more complex "under the covers" when pricing American options with a discrete dividend.  For instance, the volatility might be discontinuous around ex-date.
Question: is the bug in my understanding of the option-value, implied-volatility relationship; a bug in my test code; or, an issue with the QuantLib implementation?
(If this is a software implementation issue, I'll move this discussion to a QuantLib bug report. Thanks.)

Output
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------< cc.qpm.app:tickOptionComputation >------------------
[INFO] Building tickOptionComputation 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO]   from pom.xml
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- exec:3.4.1:java (default-cli) @ tickOptionComputation ---
SLF4J(I): Connected with provider of type [org.slf4j.simple.SimpleServiceProvider]
[cc.qpm.app.IVError.main()] INFO cc.qpm.app.IVError - loaded 48 observations
[cc.qpm.app.IVError.main()] INFO cc.qpm.app.IVError - data: 20240913 14:05:09 SPY 20240920 532 C  30.896 0.219 562.170
    value [ib w/ ib iv, ql w/ ib iv]                     30.896   30.921    0.024
    iv [ib model iv, ql iv from ib model value]           0.219    0.211   -0.008
    value [ib model, ql value from ql iv of ib value]    30.896   30.879   -0.017
...
[cc.qpm.app.IVError.main()] INFO cc.qpm.app.IVError - data: 20240913 14:05:16 SPY 20240920 548 C  15.501 0.167 562.160
    value [ib w/ ib iv, ql w/ ib iv]                     15.501   15.521    0.019
    iv [ib model iv, ql iv from ib model value]           0.167    0.165   -0.002
    value [ib model, ql value from ql iv of ib value]    15.501   15.493   -0.009

[cc.qpm.app.IVError.main()] INFO cc.qpm.app.IVError - data: 20240913 14:05:18 SPY 20240920 548 C  15.484 0.167 562.140
    value [ib w/ ib iv, ql w/ ib iv]                     15.484   15.503    0.019
    iv [ib model iv, ql iv from ib model value]           0.167    0.165   -0.002
    value [ib model, ql value from ql iv of ib value]    15.484   15.475   -0.009

[cc.qpm.app.IVError.main()] INFO cc.qpm.app.IVError - data: 20240913 14:05:08 SPY 20240920 553 C  11.132 0.155 562.190
    value [ib w/ ib iv, ql w/ ib iv]                     11.132   11.153    0.022
    iv [ib model iv, ql iv from ib model value]           0.155    0.154   -0.001
    value [ib model, ql value from ql iv of ib value]    11.132   11.125   -0.007

[cc.qpm.app.IVError.main()] INFO cc.qpm.app.IVError - data: 20240913 14:05:09 SPY 20240920 553 C  11.116 0.155 562.170
    value [ib w/ ib iv, ql w/ ib iv]                     11.116   11.137    0.022
    iv [ib model iv, ql iv from ib model value]           0.155    0.154   -0.001
    value [ib model, ql value from ql iv of ib value]    11.116   11.109   -0.007

[cc.qpm.app.IVError.main()] INFO cc.qpm.app.IVError - data: 20240913 14:05:13 SPY 20240920 553 C  11.108 0.155 562.160
    value [ib w/ ib iv, ql w/ ib iv]                     11.108   11.129    0.022
    iv [ib model iv, ql iv from ib model value]           0.155    0.154   -0.001
    value [ib model, ql value from ql iv of ib value]    11.108   11.101   -0.007

[cc.qpm.app.IVError.main()] INFO cc.qpm.app.IVError - data: 20240913 14:05:15 SPY 20240920 553 C  11.104 0.155 562.155
    value [ib w/ ib iv, ql w/ ib iv]                     11.104   11.126    0.022
    iv [ib model iv, ql iv from ib model value]           0.155    0.154   -0.001
    value [ib model, ql value from ql iv of ib value]    11.104   11.097   -0.007

[cc.qpm.app.IVError.main()] INFO cc.qpm.app.IVError - data: 20240913 14:05:16 SPY 20240920 553 C  11.108 0.155 562.160
    value [ib w/ ib iv, ql w/ ib iv]                     11.108   11.129    0.022
    iv [ib model iv, ql iv from ib model value]           0.155    0.154   -0.001
    value [ib model, ql value from ql iv of ib value]    11.108   11.101   -0.007

[cc.qpm.app.IVError.main()] INFO cc.qpm.app.IVError - data: 20240913 14:05:09 SPY 20240920 559 C   6.442 0.140 562.170
    value [ib w/ ib iv, ql w/ ib iv]                      6.442    6.458    0.016
    iv [ib model iv, ql iv from ib model value]           0.140    0.139   -0.001
    value [ib model, ql value from ql iv of ib value]     6.442    6.438   -0.004

[cc.qpm.app.IVError.main()] INFO cc.qpm.app.IVError - data: 20240913 14:05:13 SPY 20240920 559 C   6.436 0.140 562.160
    value [ib w/ ib iv, ql w/ ib iv]                      6.436    6.452    0.016
    iv [ib model iv, ql iv from ib model value]           0.140    0.139   -0.001
    value [ib model, ql value from ql iv of ib value]     6.436    6.432   -0.004

[cc.qpm.app.IVError.main()] INFO cc.qpm.app.IVError - data: 20240913 14:05:15 SPY 20240920 559 C   6.433 0.140 562.155
    value [ib w/ ib iv, ql w/ ib iv]                      6.433    6.449    0.016
    iv [ib model iv, ql iv from ib model value]           0.140    0.139   -0.001
    value [ib model, ql value from ql iv of ib value]     6.433    6.429   -0.004

[cc.qpm.app.IVError.main()] INFO cc.qpm.app.IVError - data: 20240913 14:05:16 SPY 20240920 559 C   6.436 0.140 562.160
    value [ib w/ ib iv, ql w/ ib iv]                      6.436    6.452    0.016
    iv [ib model iv, ql iv from ib model value]           0.140    0.139   -0.001
    value [ib model, ql value from ql iv of ib value]     6.436    6.432   -0.004

[cc.qpm.app.IVError.main()] INFO cc.qpm.app.IVError - data: 20240913 14:05:18 SPY 20240920 559 C   6.423 0.140 562.140
    value [ib w/ ib iv, ql w/ ib iv]                      6.423    6.439    0.016
    iv [ib model iv, ql iv from ib model value]           0.140    0.139   -0.001
    value [ib model, ql value from ql iv of ib value]     6.423    6.419   -0.004

[cc.qpm.app.IVError.main()] INFO cc.qpm.app.IVError - data: 20240913 14:05:09 SPY 20240920 532 P   0.276 0.219 562.170
    value [ib w/ ib iv, ql w/ ib iv]                      0.276    0.273   -0.003
    iv [ib model iv, ql iv from ib model value]           0.219    0.231    0.012
    value [ib model, ql value from ql iv of ib value]     0.276    0.356    0.079

[cc.qpm.app.IVError.main()] INFO cc.qpm.app.IVError - data: 20240913 14:05:13 SPY 20240920 532 P   0.277 0.219 562.160
    value [ib w/ ib iv, ql w/ ib iv]                      0.277    0.274   -0.003
    iv [ib model iv, ql iv from ib model value]           0.219    0.231    0.012
    value [ib model, ql value from ql iv of ib value]     0.277    0.356    0.079

[cc.qpm.app.IVError.main()] INFO cc.qpm.app.IVError - data: 20240913 14:05:15 SPY 20240920 532 P   0.277 0.219 562.155
    value [ib w/ ib iv, ql w/ ib iv]                      0.277    0.274   -0.003
    iv [ib model iv, ql iv from ib model value]           0.219    0.231    0.012
    value [ib model, ql value from ql iv of ib value]     0.277    0.356    0.079

[cc.qpm.app.IVError.main()] INFO cc.qpm.app.IVError - data: 20240913 14:05:16 SPY 20240920 532 P   0.277 0.219 562.160
    value [ib w/ ib iv, ql w/ ib iv]                      0.277    0.274   -0.003
    iv [ib model iv, ql iv from ib model value]           0.219    0.231    0.012
    value [ib model, ql value from ql iv of ib value]     0.277    0.356    0.079

[cc.qpm.app.IVError.main()] INFO cc.qpm.app.IVError - data: 20240913 14:05:08 SPY 20240920 541 P   0.544 0.188 562.190
    value [ib w/ ib iv, ql w/ ib iv]                      0.544    0.539   -0.004
    iv [ib model iv, ql iv from ib model value]           0.188    0.201    0.013
    value [ib model, ql value from ql iv of ib value]     0.544    0.700    0.157

[cc.qpm.app.IVError.main()] INFO cc.qpm.app.IVError - data: 20240913 14:05:09 SPY 20240920 541 P   0.545 0.188 562.170
    value [ib w/ ib iv, ql w/ ib iv]                      0.545    0.541   -0.004
    iv [ib model iv, ql iv from ib model value]           0.188    0.201    0.013
    value [ib model, ql value from ql iv of ib value]     0.545    0.702    0.157

[cc.qpm.app.IVError.main()] INFO cc.qpm.app.IVError - data: 20240913 14:05:13 SPY 20240920 541 P   0.546 0.188 562.160
    value [ib w/ ib iv, ql w/ ib iv]                      0.546    0.542   -0.005
    iv [ib model iv, ql iv from ib model value]           0.188    0.201    0.013
    value [ib model, ql value from ql iv of ib value]     0.546    0.703    0.157

[cc.qpm.app.IVError.main()] INFO cc.qpm.app.IVError - data: 20240913 14:05:15 SPY 20240920 541 P   0.547 0.188 562.155
    value [ib w/ ib iv, ql w/ ib iv]                      0.547    0.542   -0.005
    iv [ib model iv, ql iv from ib model value]           0.188    0.201    0.013
    value [ib model, ql value from ql iv of ib value]     0.547    0.704    0.157

[cc.qpm.app.IVError.main()] INFO cc.qpm.app.IVError - data: 20240913 14:05:16 SPY 20240920 541 P   0.546 0.188 562.160
    value [ib w/ ib iv, ql w/ ib iv]                      0.546    0.542   -0.005
    iv [ib model iv, ql iv from ib model value]           0.188    0.201    0.013
    value [ib model, ql value from ql iv of ib value]     0.546    0.703    0.157

[cc.qpm.app.IVError.main()] INFO cc.qpm.app.IVError - data: 20240913 14:05:09 SPY 20240920 548 P   1.071 0.167 562.170
    value [ib w/ ib iv, ql w/ ib iv]                      1.071    1.053   -0.019
    iv [ib model iv, ql iv from ib model value]           0.167    0.183    0.016
    value [ib model, ql value from ql iv of ib value]     1.071    1.360    0.289

[cc.qpm.app.IVError.main()] INFO cc.qpm.app.IVError - data: 20240913 14:05:13 SPY 20240920 548 P   1.073 0.167 562.160
    value [ib w/ ib iv, ql w/ ib iv]                      1.073    1.054   -0.019
    iv [ib model iv, ql iv from ib model value]           0.167    0.183    0.016
    value [ib model, ql value from ql iv of ib value]     1.073    1.362    0.289

[cc.qpm.app.IVError.main()] INFO cc.qpm.app.IVError - data: 20240913 14:05:15 SPY 20240920 548 P   1.074 0.167 562.155
    value [ib w/ ib iv, ql w/ ib iv]                      1.074    1.055   -0.019
    iv [ib model iv, ql iv from ib model value]           0.167    0.183    0.016
    value [ib model, ql value from ql iv of ib value]     1.074    1.363    0.289

[cc.qpm.app.IVError.main()] INFO cc.qpm.app.IVError - data: 20240913 14:05:16 SPY 20240920 548 P   1.073 0.167 562.160
    value [ib w/ ib iv, ql w/ ib iv]                      1.073    1.054   -0.019
    iv [ib model iv, ql iv from ib model value]           0.167    0.183    0.016
    value [ib model, ql value from ql iv of ib value]     1.073    1.362    0.289

[cc.qpm.app.IVError.main()] INFO cc.qpm.app.IVError - data: 20240913 14:05:18 SPY 20240920 548 P   1.076 0.167 562.140
    value [ib w/ ib iv, ql w/ ib iv]                      1.076    1.057   -0.019
    iv [ib model iv, ql iv from ib model value]           0.167    0.183    0.016
    value [ib model, ql value from ql iv of ib value]     1.076    1.366    0.290

[cc.qpm.app.IVError.main()] INFO cc.qpm.app.IVError - data: 20240913 14:05:08 SPY 20240920 553 P   1.827 0.155 562.190
    value [ib w/ ib iv, ql w/ ib iv]                      1.827    1.809   -0.018
    iv [ib model iv, ql iv from ib model value]           0.155    0.173    0.018
    value [ib model, ql value from ql iv of ib value]     1.827    2.274    0.446

[cc.qpm.app.IVError.main()] INFO cc.qpm.app.IVError - data: 20240913 14:05:09 SPY 20240920 553 P   1.832 0.155 562.170
    value [ib w/ ib iv, ql w/ ib iv]                      1.832    1.814   -0.017
    iv [ib model iv, ql iv from ib model value]           0.155    0.173    0.018
    value [ib model, ql value from ql iv of ib value]     1.832    2.279    0.447

[cc.qpm.app.IVError.main()] INFO cc.qpm.app.IVError - data: 20240913 14:05:13 SPY 20240920 553 P   1.834 0.155 562.160
    value [ib w/ ib iv, ql w/ ib iv]                      1.834    1.817   -0.017
    iv [ib model iv, ql iv from ib model value]           0.155    0.173    0.018
    value [ib model, ql value from ql iv of ib value]     1.834    2.281    0.448

[cc.qpm.app.IVError.main()] INFO cc.qpm.app.IVError - data: 20240913 14:05:15 SPY 20240920 553 P   1.835 0.155 562.155
    value [ib w/ ib iv, ql w/ ib iv]                      1.835    1.818   -0.017
    iv [ib model iv, ql iv from ib model value]           0.155    0.173    0.018
    value [ib model, ql value from ql iv of ib value]     1.835    2.283    0.448

[cc.qpm.app.IVError.main()] INFO cc.qpm.app.IVError - data: 20240913 14:05:16 SPY 20240920 553 P   1.834 0.155 562.160
    value [ib w/ ib iv, ql w/ ib iv]                      1.834    1.817   -0.017
    iv [ib model iv, ql iv from ib model value]           0.155    0.173    0.018
    value [ib model, ql value from ql iv of ib value]     1.834    2.281    0.448

[cc.qpm.app.IVError.main()] INFO cc.qpm.app.IVError - data: 20240913 14:05:09 SPY 20240920 559 P   3.458 0.140 562.170
    value [ib w/ ib iv, ql w/ ib iv]                      3.458    3.422   -0.036
    iv [ib model iv, ql iv from ib model value]           0.140    0.164    0.024
    value [ib model, ql value from ql iv of ib value]     3.458    4.170    0.712

[cc.qpm.app.IVError.main()] INFO cc.qpm.app.IVError - data: 20240913 14:05:13 SPY 20240920 559 P   3.463 0.140 562.160
    value [ib w/ ib iv, ql w/ ib iv]                      3.463    3.427   -0.036
    iv [ib model iv, ql iv from ib model value]           0.140    0.164    0.024
    value [ib model, ql value from ql iv of ib value]     3.463    4.175    0.712

[cc.qpm.app.IVError.main()] INFO cc.qpm.app.IVError - data: 20240913 14:05:15 SPY 20240920 559 P   3.465 0.140 562.155
    value [ib w/ ib iv, ql w/ ib iv]                      3.465    3.429   -0.036
    iv [ib model iv, ql iv from ib model value]           0.140    0.164    0.024
    value [ib model, ql value from ql iv of ib value]     3.465    4.178    0.713

[cc.qpm.app.IVError.main()] INFO cc.qpm.app.IVError - data: 20240913 14:05:16 SPY 20240920 559 P   3.463 0.140 562.160
    value [ib w/ ib iv, ql w/ ib iv]                      3.463    3.427   -0.036
    iv [ib model iv, ql iv from ib model value]           0.140    0.164    0.024
    value [ib model, ql value from ql iv of ib value]     3.463    4.175    0.712

[cc.qpm.app.IVError.main()] INFO cc.qpm.app.IVError - data: 20240913 14:05:18 SPY 20240920 559 P   3.472 0.140 562.140
    value [ib w/ ib iv, ql w/ ib iv]                      3.472    3.435   -0.036
    iv [ib model iv, ql iv from ib model value]           0.140    0.164    0.024
    value [ib model, ql value from ql iv of ib value]     3.472    4.185    0.713

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  2.721 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2024-09-15T12:47:26-04:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------


Main class
import java.util.List;

import org.quantlib.Actual365Fixed;
import org.quantlib.AmericanExercise;
import org.quantlib.BlackConstantVol;
import org.quantlib.BlackScholesMertonProcess;
import org.quantlib.BlackVolTermStructureHandle;
import org.quantlib.Calendar;
import org.quantlib.DateParser;
import org.quantlib.DayCounter;
import org.quantlib.DividendSchedule;
import org.quantlib.Exercise;
import org.quantlib.FdBlackScholesVanillaEngine;
import org.quantlib.FixedDividend;
import org.quantlib.FlatForward;
import org.quantlib.PlainVanillaPayoff;
import org.quantlib.QuoteHandle;
import org.quantlib.Settings;
import org.quantlib.SimpleQuote;
import org.quantlib.UnitedStates;
import org.quantlib.VanillaOption;
import org.quantlib.YieldTermStructureHandle;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class IVError {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double riskFreeRate = 0.0533;
        DayCounter dayCounter = new Actual365Fixed();
        Calendar calendar = new UnitedStates(UnitedStates.Market.NYSE);

        // data obtained 9/13/2024 for SPY
        FixedDividend fixedDividend = new FixedDividend(1.76, DateParser.parseFormatted("20240920", "%Y%m%d"));
        DividendSchedule dividendSchedule = new DividendSchedule();
        dividendSchedule.add(fixedDividend);

        List<Observation> obs = Observation.readData();
        logger.info(String.format("loaded %d observations", obs.size()));

        for (Observation o : obs) {
            PlainVanillaPayoff payoff = new PlainVanillaPayoff(o.optType(), o.strike());
            Exercise americanExercise = new AmericanExercise(o.evalDate(), o.expiryDate());
            VanillaOption americanOption = new VanillaOption(payoff, americanExercise);

            Settings.instance().setEvaluationDate(o.evalDate());

            QuoteHandle underlyingH = new QuoteHandle(new SimpleQuote(o.underValue()));
            YieldTermStructureHandle flatDividendYield = new YieldTermStructureHandle(
                    new FlatForward(o.evalDate(), 0, dayCounter));
            YieldTermStructureHandle flatTermStructure = new YieldTermStructureHandle(
                    new FlatForward(o.evalDate(), riskFreeRate, dayCounter));
            BlackVolTermStructureHandle flatVolatility = new BlackVolTermStructureHandle(
                    new BlackConstantVol(o.evalDate(), calendar, o.modelIV(), dayCounter));

            BlackScholesMertonProcess stochasticProcess = new BlackScholesMertonProcess(underlyingH, flatDividendYield,
                    flatTermStructure, flatVolatility);

            // price option using IBKR model IV
            americanOption.setPricingEngine(new FdBlackScholesVanillaEngine(stochasticProcess, dividendSchedule));
            double qlnpv_ibiv = americanOption.NPV();
            
            // obtain implied volatility for IBKR model value
            double qliv = americanOption.impliedVolatility(o.modelValue(), stochasticProcess);
            
            // price option using QL implied volatility for IBKR model value
            flatVolatility = new BlackVolTermStructureHandle(
                    new BlackConstantVol(o.evalDate(), calendar, qliv, dayCounter));
            stochasticProcess = new BlackScholesMertonProcess(underlyingH, flatDividendYield,
                    flatTermStructure, flatVolatility);
            americanOption.setPricingEngine(new FdBlackScholesVanillaEngine(stochasticProcess, dividendSchedule));
            
            double qlnpv_qliv = americanOption.NPV();

            String a = String.format("\t%-50s %8.3f %8.3f %8.3f", "value [ib w/ ib iv, ql w/ ib iv]",o.modelValue(),qlnpv_ibiv,qlnpv_ibiv-o.modelValue());
            String b = String.format("\t%-50s %8.3f %8.3f %8.3f", "iv [ib model iv, ql iv from ib model value]",o.modelIV(),qliv,qliv-o.modelIV());
            String c = String.format("\t%-50s %8.3f %8.3f %8.3f", "value [ib model, ql value from ql iv of ib value]",o.modelValue(),qlnpv_qliv,qlnpv_qliv-o.modelValue());
            logger.info("data: "+o.toString()+"\n" + a + "\n" + b + "\n" + c + "\n");
        }
    }

    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(IVError.class);

}


Data
package cc.qpm.app;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.quantlib.Date;
import org.quantlib.DateParser;
import org.quantlib.Option;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class Observation {

    public Observation(Object[] d) {
        int i = 0;
        modelDateTime = (String) d[i++];
        symbol = (String) d[i++];
        expiry = (String) d[i++];
        strike = (double) (int) d[i++];
        right = (String) d[i++];
        modelValue = (double) d[i++];
        modelIV = (double) d[i++];
        underValue = (double) d[i++];
    }

    public static List<Observation> readData() {
        List<Observation> obs = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Object[] d : data) {
            obs.add(new Observation(d));
            logger.debug(obs.get(obs.size() - 1).toString());
        }
        return obs;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%s %s %s %d %s %7.3f %.3f %.3f", modelDateTime, symbol, expiry, (int) strike, right,
                modelValue, modelIV, underValue);
    }

    private static Object[][] data = { 
            { "20240913 14:05:09", "SPY", "20240920", 532, "C", 30.8963, 0.219, 562.170 },
            { "20240913 14:05:13", "SPY", "20240920", 532, "C", 30.8867, 0.219, 562.160 },
            { "20240913 14:05:15", "SPY", "20240920", 532, "C", 30.8819, 0.219, 562.155 },
            { "20240913 14:05:16", "SPY", "20240920", 532, "C", 30.8867, 0.219, 562.160 },
            { "20240913 14:05:08", "SPY", "20240920", 541, "C", 22.1220, 0.188, 562.190 },
            { "20240913 14:05:09", "SPY", "20240920", 541, "C", 22.1032, 0.188, 562.170 },
            { "20240913 14:05:13", "SPY", "20240920", 541, "C", 22.0938, 0.188, 562.160 },
            { "20240913 14:05:15", "SPY", "20240920", 541, "C", 22.0891, 0.188, 562.155 },
            { "20240913 14:05:16", "SPY", "20240920", 541, "C", 22.0938, 0.188, 562.160 },
            { "20240913 14:05:09", "SPY", "20240920", 548, "C", 15.5102, 0.167, 562.170 },
            { "20240913 14:05:13", "SPY", "20240920", 548, "C", 15.5014, 0.167, 562.160 },
            { "20240913 14:05:15", "SPY", "20240920", 548, "C", 15.4970, 0.167, 562.155 },
            { "20240913 14:05:16", "SPY", "20240920", 548, "C", 15.5014, 0.167, 562.160 },
            { "20240913 14:05:18", "SPY", "20240920", 548, "C", 15.4838, 0.167, 562.140 },
            { "20240913 14:05:08", "SPY", "20240920", 553, "C", 11.1315, 0.155, 562.190 },
            { "20240913 14:05:09", "SPY", "20240920", 553, "C", 11.1157, 0.155, 562.170 },
            { "20240913 14:05:13", "SPY", "20240920", 553, "C", 11.1078, 0.155, 562.160 },
            { "20240913 14:05:15", "SPY", "20240920", 553, "C", 11.1038, 0.155, 562.155 },
            { "20240913 14:05:16", "SPY", "20240920", 553, "C", 11.1078, 0.155, 562.160 },
            { "20240913 14:05:09", "SPY", "20240920", 559, "C", 6.44227, 0.140, 562.170 },
            { "20240913 14:05:13", "SPY", "20240920", 559, "C", 6.43585, 0.140, 562.160 },
            { "20240913 14:05:15", "SPY", "20240920", 559, "C", 6.43267, 0.140, 562.155 },
            { "20240913 14:05:16", "SPY", "20240920", 559, "C", 6.43585, 0.140, 562.160 },
            { "20240913 14:05:18", "SPY", "20240920", 559, "C", 6.42303, 0.140, 562.140 },
            { "20240913 14:05:09", "SPY", "20240920", 532, "P", 0.276421, 0.219, 562.170 },
            { "20240913 14:05:13", "SPY", "20240920", 532, "P", 0.276821, 0.219, 562.160 },
            { "20240913 14:05:15", "SPY", "20240920", 532, "P", 0.277018, 0.219, 562.155 },
            { "20240913 14:05:16", "SPY", "20240920", 532, "P", 0.276821, 0.219, 562.160 },
            { "20240913 14:05:08", "SPY", "20240920", 541, "P", 0.543506, 0.188, 562.190 },
            { "20240913 14:05:09", "SPY", "20240920", 541, "P", 0.545269, 0.188, 562.170 },
            { "20240913 14:05:13", "SPY", "20240920", 541, "P", 0.546150, 0.188, 562.160 },
            { "20240913 14:05:15", "SPY", "20240920", 541, "P", 0.546586, 0.188, 562.155 },
            { "20240913 14:05:16", "SPY", "20240920", 541, "P", 0.546150, 0.188, 562.160 },
            { "20240913 14:05:09", "SPY", "20240920", 548, "P", 1.07105, 0.167, 562.170 },
            { "20240913 14:05:13", "SPY", "20240920", 548, "P", 1.07274, 0.167, 562.160 },
            { "20240913 14:05:15", "SPY", "20240920", 548, "P", 1.07358, 0.167, 562.155 },
            { "20240913 14:05:16", "SPY", "20240920", 548, "P", 1.07274, 0.167, 562.160 },
            { "20240913 14:05:18", "SPY", "20240920", 548, "P", 1.07613, 0.167, 562.140 },
            { "20240913 14:05:08", "SPY", "20240920", 553, "P", 1.82722, 0.155, 562.190 },
            { "20240913 14:05:09", "SPY", "20240920", 553, "P", 1.83171, 0.155, 562.170 },
            { "20240913 14:05:13", "SPY", "20240920", 553, "P", 1.83396, 0.155, 562.160 },
            { "20240913 14:05:15", "SPY", "20240920", 553, "P", 1.83507, 0.155, 562.155 },
            { "20240913 14:05:16", "SPY", "20240920", 553, "P", 1.83396, 0.155, 562.160 },
            { "20240913 14:05:09", "SPY", "20240920", 559, "P", 3.45848, 0.140, 562.170 },
            { "20240913 14:05:13", "SPY", "20240920", 559, "P", 3.46284, 0.140, 562.160 },
            { "20240913 14:05:15", "SPY", "20240920", 559, "P", 3.46500, 0.140, 562.155 },
            { "20240913 14:05:16", "SPY", "20240920", 559, "P", 3.46284, 0.140, 562.160 },
            { "20240913 14:05:18", "SPY", "20240920", 559, "P", 3.47154, 0.140, 562.140 } 
            };

    private String modelDateTime; public Date evalDate() {return DateParser.parseFormatted(modelDateTime.split(" ")[0], "%Y%m%d");}
    private String symbol; public String symbol() {return symbol;}
    private String expiry; public Date expiryDate()  {return DateParser.parseFormatted(expiry, "%Y%m%d");}
    private double strike; public double strike() {return strike;}
    private String right; public Option.Type optType() {return right.equalsIgnoreCase("C")? Option.Type.Call : Option.Type.Put;}
    private double modelValue; public double modelValue() {return modelValue;}
    private double modelIV; public double modelIV() {return modelIV;}
    private double underValue; public double underValue() {return underValue;}

    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Observation.class);

}


A similar QuantLib GitHub issue: https://github.com/lballabio/QuantLib/issues/850#issuecomment-650742609

There was an error in my test code.
diff output comparing original-incorrect and updated-revised code is:
                        // obtain implied volatility for IBKR model value
-                       double qliv = americanOption.impliedVolatility(o.modelValue(), stochasticProcess);
+                       double qliv = americanOption.impliedVolatility(o.modelValue(), stochasticProcess, dividendSchedule);
  

Note I needed to provide the dividendSchedule.
All test cases now show a zero difference for the sanity-check:
$$f\left(f^{-1}\left(\textrm{option-value}\right)\right) - \textrm{option-value}~.$$

Revised output:
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------< cc.qpm.app:tickOptionComputation >------------------
[INFO] Building tickOptionComputation 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO]   from pom.xml
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- exec:3.4.1:java (default-cli) @ tickOptionComputation ---
SLF4J(I): Connected with provider of type [org.slf4j.simple.SimpleServiceProvider]
[cc.qpm.app.IVError.main()] INFO cc.qpm.app.IVError - loaded 48 observations
[cc.qpm.app.IVError.main()] INFO cc.qpm.app.IVError - data: 20240913 14:05:09 SPY 20240920 532 C  30.896 0.219 562.170
    value [ib w/ ib iv, ql w/ ib iv]                     30.896   30.921    0.024
    iv [ib model iv, ql iv from ib model value]           0.219    0.214   -0.005
    value [ib model, ql value from ql iv of ib value]    30.896   30.896   -0.000

[cc.qpm.app.IVError.main()] INFO cc.qpm.app.IVError - data: 20240913 14:05:13 SPY 20240920 532 C  30.887 0.219 562.160
    value [ib w/ ib iv, ql w/ ib iv]                     30.887   30.911    0.024
    iv [ib model iv, ql iv from ib model value]           0.219    0.214   -0.005
    value [ib model, ql value from ql iv of ib value]    30.887   30.887   -0.000

[cc.qpm.app.IVError.main()] INFO cc.qpm.app.IVError - data: 20240913 14:05:15 SPY 20240920 532 C  30.882 0.219 562.155
    value [ib w/ ib iv, ql w/ ib iv]                     30.882   30.906    0.024
    iv [ib model iv, ql iv from ib model value]           0.219    0.214   -0.005
    value [ib model, ql value from ql iv of ib value]    30.882   30.882   -0.000

[cc.qpm.app.IVError.main()] INFO cc.qpm.app.IVError - data: 20240913 14:05:16 SPY 20240920 532 C  30.887 0.219 562.160
    value [ib w/ ib iv, ql w/ ib iv]                     30.887   30.911    0.024
    iv [ib model iv, ql iv from ib model value]           0.219    0.214   -0.005
    value [ib model, ql value from ql iv of ib value]    30.887   30.887   -0.000

[cc.qpm.app.IVError.main()] INFO cc.qpm.app.IVError - data: 20240913 14:05:08 SPY 20240920 541 C  22.122 0.188 562.190
    value [ib w/ ib iv, ql w/ ib iv]                     22.122   22.149    0.027
    iv [ib model iv, ql iv from ib model value]           0.188    0.185   -0.003
    value [ib model, ql value from ql iv of ib value]    22.122   22.122    0.000

[cc.qpm.app.IVError.main()] INFO cc.qpm.app.IVError - data: 20240913 14:05:09 SPY 20240920 541 C  22.103 0.188 562.170
    value [ib w/ ib iv, ql w/ ib iv]                     22.103   22.130    0.027
    iv [ib model iv, ql iv from ib model value]           0.188    0.185   -0.003
    value [ib model, ql value from ql iv of ib value]    22.103   22.103    0.000

[cc.qpm.app.IVError.main()] INFO cc.qpm.app.IVError - data: 20240913 14:05:13 SPY 20240920 541 C  22.094 0.188 562.160
    value [ib w/ ib iv, ql w/ ib iv]                     22.094   22.121    0.027
    iv [ib model iv, ql iv from ib model value]           0.188    0.185   -0.003
    value [ib model, ql value from ql iv of ib value]    22.094   22.094    0.000

[cc.qpm.app.IVError.main()] INFO cc.qpm.app.IVError - data: 20240913 14:05:15 SPY 20240920 541 C  22.089 0.188 562.155
    value [ib w/ ib iv, ql w/ ib iv]                     22.089   22.116    0.027
    iv [ib model iv, ql iv from ib model value]           0.188    0.185   -0.003
    value [ib model, ql value from ql iv of ib value]    22.089   22.089    0.000

[cc.qpm.app.IVError.main()] INFO cc.qpm.app.IVError - data: 20240913 14:05:16 SPY 20240920 541 C  22.094 0.188 562.160
    value [ib w/ ib iv, ql w/ ib iv]                     22.094   22.121    0.027
    iv [ib model iv, ql iv from ib model value]           0.188    0.185   -0.003
    value [ib model, ql value from ql iv of ib value]    22.094   22.094    0.000

[cc.qpm.app.IVError.main()] INFO cc.qpm.app.IVError - data: 20240913 14:05:09 SPY 20240920 548 C  15.510 0.167 562.170
    value [ib w/ ib iv, ql w/ ib iv]                     15.510   15.529    0.019
    iv [ib model iv, ql iv from ib model value]           0.167    0.166   -0.001
    value [ib model, ql value from ql iv of ib value]    15.510   15.510    0.000

[cc.qpm.app.IVError.main()] INFO cc.qpm.app.IVError - data: 20240913 14:05:13 SPY 20240920 548 C  15.501 0.167 562.160
    value [ib w/ ib iv, ql w/ ib iv]                     15.501   15.521    0.019
    iv [ib model iv, ql iv from ib model value]           0.167    0.166   -0.001
    value [ib model, ql value from ql iv of ib value]    15.501   15.501    0.000

[cc.qpm.app.IVError.main()] INFO cc.qpm.app.IVError - data: 20240913 14:05:15 SPY 20240920 548 C  15.497 0.167 562.155
    value [ib w/ ib iv, ql w/ ib iv]                     15.497   15.516    0.019
    iv [ib model iv, ql iv from ib model value]           0.167    0.166   -0.001
    value [ib model, ql value from ql iv of ib value]    15.497   15.497    0.000

[cc.qpm.app.IVError.main()] INFO cc.qpm.app.IVError - data: 20240913 14:05:16 SPY 20240920 548 C  15.501 0.167 562.160
    value [ib w/ ib iv, ql w/ ib iv]                     15.501   15.521    0.019
    iv [ib model iv, ql iv from ib model value]           0.167    0.166   -0.001
    value [ib model, ql value from ql iv of ib value]    15.501   15.501    0.000

[cc.qpm.app.IVError.main()] INFO cc.qpm.app.IVError - data: 20240913 14:05:18 SPY 20240920 548 C  15.484 0.167 562.140
    value [ib w/ ib iv, ql w/ ib iv]                     15.484   15.503    0.019
    iv [ib model iv, ql iv from ib model value]           0.167    0.166   -0.001
    value [ib model, ql value from ql iv of ib value]    15.484   15.484    0.000

[cc.qpm.app.IVError.main()] INFO cc.qpm.app.IVError - data: 20240913 14:05:08 SPY 20240920 553 C  11.132 0.155 562.190
    value [ib w/ ib iv, ql w/ ib iv]                     11.132   11.153    0.022
    iv [ib model iv, ql iv from ib model value]           0.155    0.154   -0.001
    value [ib model, ql value from ql iv of ib value]    11.132   11.131   -0.000

[cc.qpm.app.IVError.main()] INFO cc.qpm.app.IVError - data: 20240913 14:05:09 SPY 20240920 553 C  11.116 0.155 562.170
    value [ib w/ ib iv, ql w/ ib iv]                     11.116   11.137    0.022
    iv [ib model iv, ql iv from ib model value]           0.155    0.154   -0.001
    value [ib model, ql value from ql iv of ib value]    11.116   11.115   -0.000

[cc.qpm.app.IVError.main()] INFO cc.qpm.app.IVError - data: 20240913 14:05:13 SPY 20240920 553 C  11.108 0.155 562.160
    value [ib w/ ib iv, ql w/ ib iv]                     11.108   11.129    0.022
    iv [ib model iv, ql iv from ib model value]           0.155    0.154   -0.001
    value [ib model, ql value from ql iv of ib value]    11.108   11.107   -0.000

[cc.qpm.app.IVError.main()] INFO cc.qpm.app.IVError - data: 20240913 14:05:15 SPY 20240920 553 C  11.104 0.155 562.155
    value [ib w/ ib iv, ql w/ ib iv]                     11.104   11.126    0.022
    iv [ib model iv, ql iv from ib model value]           0.155    0.154   -0.001
    value [ib model, ql value from ql iv of ib value]    11.104   11.103   -0.000

[cc.qpm.app.IVError.main()] INFO cc.qpm.app.IVError - data: 20240913 14:05:16 SPY 20240920 553 C  11.108 0.155 562.160
    value [ib w/ ib iv, ql w/ ib iv]                     11.108   11.129    0.022
    iv [ib model iv, ql iv from ib model value]           0.155    0.154   -0.001
    value [ib model, ql value from ql iv of ib value]    11.108   11.107   -0.000

[cc.qpm.app.IVError.main()] INFO cc.qpm.app.IVError - data: 20240913 14:05:09 SPY 20240920 559 C   6.442 0.140 562.170
    value [ib w/ ib iv, ql w/ ib iv]                      6.442    6.458    0.016
    iv [ib model iv, ql iv from ib model value]           0.140    0.139   -0.001
    value [ib model, ql value from ql iv of ib value]     6.442    6.442   -0.000

[cc.qpm.app.IVError.main()] INFO cc.qpm.app.IVError - data: 20240913 14:05:13 SPY 20240920 559 C   6.436 0.140 562.160
    value [ib w/ ib iv, ql w/ ib iv]                      6.436    6.452    0.016
    iv [ib model iv, ql iv from ib model value]           0.140    0.139   -0.001
    value [ib model, ql value from ql iv of ib value]     6.436    6.435   -0.000

[cc.qpm.app.IVError.main()] INFO cc.qpm.app.IVError - data: 20240913 14:05:15 SPY 20240920 559 C   6.433 0.140 562.155
    value [ib w/ ib iv, ql w/ ib iv]                      6.433    6.449    0.016
    iv [ib model iv, ql iv from ib model value]           0.140    0.139   -0.001
    value [ib model, ql value from ql iv of ib value]     6.433    6.432   -0.000

[cc.qpm.app.IVError.main()] INFO cc.qpm.app.IVError - data: 20240913 14:05:16 SPY 20240920 559 C   6.436 0.140 562.160
    value [ib w/ ib iv, ql w/ ib iv]                      6.436    6.452    0.016
    iv [ib model iv, ql iv from ib model value]           0.140    0.139   -0.001
    value [ib model, ql value from ql iv of ib value]     6.436    6.435   -0.000

[cc.qpm.app.IVError.main()] INFO cc.qpm.app.IVError - data: 20240913 14:05:18 SPY 20240920 559 C   6.423 0.140 562.140
    value [ib w/ ib iv, ql w/ ib iv]                      6.423    6.439    0.016
    iv [ib model iv, ql iv from ib model value]           0.140    0.139   -0.001
    value [ib model, ql value from ql iv of ib value]     6.423    6.423   -0.000

[cc.qpm.app.IVError.main()] INFO cc.qpm.app.IVError - data: 20240913 14:05:09 SPY 20240920 532 P   0.276 0.219 562.170
    value [ib w/ ib iv, ql w/ ib iv]                      0.276    0.273   -0.003
    iv [ib model iv, ql iv from ib model value]           0.219    0.219    0.000
    value [ib model, ql value from ql iv of ib value]     0.276    0.276   -0.000

[cc.qpm.app.IVError.main()] INFO cc.qpm.app.IVError - data: 20240913 14:05:13 SPY 20240920 532 P   0.277 0.219 562.160
    value [ib w/ ib iv, ql w/ ib iv]                      0.277    0.274   -0.003
    iv [ib model iv, ql iv from ib model value]           0.219    0.219    0.000
    value [ib model, ql value from ql iv of ib value]     0.277    0.277   -0.000

[cc.qpm.app.IVError.main()] INFO cc.qpm.app.IVError - data: 20240913 14:05:15 SPY 20240920 532 P   0.277 0.219 562.155
    value [ib w/ ib iv, ql w/ ib iv]                      0.277    0.274   -0.003
    iv [ib model iv, ql iv from ib model value]           0.219    0.219    0.000
    value [ib model, ql value from ql iv of ib value]     0.277    0.277   -0.000

[cc.qpm.app.IVError.main()] INFO cc.qpm.app.IVError - data: 20240913 14:05:16 SPY 20240920 532 P   0.277 0.219 562.160
    value [ib w/ ib iv, ql w/ ib iv]                      0.277    0.274   -0.003
    iv [ib model iv, ql iv from ib model value]           0.219    0.219    0.000
    value [ib model, ql value from ql iv of ib value]     0.277    0.277   -0.000

[cc.qpm.app.IVError.main()] INFO cc.qpm.app.IVError - data: 20240913 14:05:08 SPY 20240920 541 P   0.544 0.188 562.190
    value [ib w/ ib iv, ql w/ ib iv]                      0.544    0.539   -0.004
    iv [ib model iv, ql iv from ib model value]           0.188    0.188    0.000
    value [ib model, ql value from ql iv of ib value]     0.544    0.544    0.000

[cc.qpm.app.IVError.main()] INFO cc.qpm.app.IVError - data: 20240913 14:05:09 SPY 20240920 541 P   0.545 0.188 562.170
    value [ib w/ ib iv, ql w/ ib iv]                      0.545    0.541   -0.004
    iv [ib model iv, ql iv from ib model value]           0.188    0.188    0.000
    value [ib model, ql value from ql iv of ib value]     0.545    0.546    0.000

[cc.qpm.app.IVError.main()] INFO cc.qpm.app.IVError - data: 20240913 14:05:13 SPY 20240920 541 P   0.546 0.188 562.160
    value [ib w/ ib iv, ql w/ ib iv]                      0.546    0.542   -0.005
    iv [ib model iv, ql iv from ib model value]           0.188    0.188    0.000
    value [ib model, ql value from ql iv of ib value]     0.546    0.546    0.000

[cc.qpm.app.IVError.main()] INFO cc.qpm.app.IVError - data: 20240913 14:05:15 SPY 20240920 541 P   0.547 0.188 562.155
    value [ib w/ ib iv, ql w/ ib iv]                      0.547    0.542   -0.005
    iv [ib model iv, ql iv from ib model value]           0.188    0.188    0.000
    value [ib model, ql value from ql iv of ib value]     0.547    0.547    0.000

[cc.qpm.app.IVError.main()] INFO cc.qpm.app.IVError - data: 20240913 14:05:16 SPY 20240920 541 P   0.546 0.188 562.160
    value [ib w/ ib iv, ql w/ ib iv]                      0.546    0.542   -0.005
    iv [ib model iv, ql iv from ib model value]           0.188    0.188    0.000
    value [ib model, ql value from ql iv of ib value]     0.546    0.546    0.000

[cc.qpm.app.IVError.main()] INFO cc.qpm.app.IVError - data: 20240913 14:05:09 SPY 20240920 548 P   1.071 0.167 562.170
    value [ib w/ ib iv, ql w/ ib iv]                      1.071    1.053   -0.019
    iv [ib model iv, ql iv from ib model value]           0.167    0.168    0.001
    value [ib model, ql value from ql iv of ib value]     1.071    1.071   -0.000

[cc.qpm.app.IVError.main()] INFO cc.qpm.app.IVError - data: 20240913 14:05:13 SPY 20240920 548 P   1.073 0.167 562.160
    value [ib w/ ib iv, ql w/ ib iv]                      1.073    1.054   -0.019
    iv [ib model iv, ql iv from ib model value]           0.167    0.168    0.001
    value [ib model, ql value from ql iv of ib value]     1.073    1.073   -0.000

[cc.qpm.app.IVError.main()] INFO cc.qpm.app.IVError - data: 20240913 14:05:15 SPY 20240920 548 P   1.074 0.167 562.155
    value [ib w/ ib iv, ql w/ ib iv]                      1.074    1.055   -0.019
    iv [ib model iv, ql iv from ib model value]           0.167    0.168    0.001
    value [ib model, ql value from ql iv of ib value]     1.074    1.073   -0.000

[cc.qpm.app.IVError.main()] INFO cc.qpm.app.IVError - data: 20240913 14:05:16 SPY 20240920 548 P   1.073 0.167 562.160
    value [ib w/ ib iv, ql w/ ib iv]                      1.073    1.054   -0.019
    iv [ib model iv, ql iv from ib model value]           0.167    0.168    0.001
    value [ib model, ql value from ql iv of ib value]     1.073    1.073   -0.000

[cc.qpm.app.IVError.main()] INFO cc.qpm.app.IVError - data: 20240913 14:05:18 SPY 20240920 548 P   1.076 0.167 562.140
    value [ib w/ ib iv, ql w/ ib iv]                      1.076    1.057   -0.019
    iv [ib model iv, ql iv from ib model value]           0.167    0.168    0.001
    value [ib model, ql value from ql iv of ib value]     1.076    1.076   -0.000

[cc.qpm.app.IVError.main()] INFO cc.qpm.app.IVError - data: 20240913 14:05:08 SPY 20240920 553 P   1.827 0.155 562.190
    value [ib w/ ib iv, ql w/ ib iv]                      1.827    1.809   -0.018
    iv [ib model iv, ql iv from ib model value]           0.155    0.156    0.001
    value [ib model, ql value from ql iv of ib value]     1.827    1.827   -0.000

[cc.qpm.app.IVError.main()] INFO cc.qpm.app.IVError - data: 20240913 14:05:09 SPY 20240920 553 P   1.832 0.155 562.170
    value [ib w/ ib iv, ql w/ ib iv]                      1.832    1.814   -0.017
    iv [ib model iv, ql iv from ib model value]           0.155    0.156    0.001
    value [ib model, ql value from ql iv of ib value]     1.832    1.831   -0.000

[cc.qpm.app.IVError.main()] INFO cc.qpm.app.IVError - data: 20240913 14:05:13 SPY 20240920 553 P   1.834 0.155 562.160
    value [ib w/ ib iv, ql w/ ib iv]                      1.834    1.817   -0.017
    iv [ib model iv, ql iv from ib model value]           0.155    0.156    0.001
    value [ib model, ql value from ql iv of ib value]     1.834    1.834   -0.000

[cc.qpm.app.IVError.main()] INFO cc.qpm.app.IVError - data: 20240913 14:05:15 SPY 20240920 553 P   1.835 0.155 562.155
    value [ib w/ ib iv, ql w/ ib iv]                      1.835    1.818   -0.017
    iv [ib model iv, ql iv from ib model value]           0.155    0.156    0.001
    value [ib model, ql value from ql iv of ib value]     1.835    1.835   -0.000

[cc.qpm.app.IVError.main()] INFO cc.qpm.app.IVError - data: 20240913 14:05:16 SPY 20240920 553 P   1.834 0.155 562.160
    value [ib w/ ib iv, ql w/ ib iv]                      1.834    1.817   -0.017
    iv [ib model iv, ql iv from ib model value]           0.155    0.156    0.001
    value [ib model, ql value from ql iv of ib value]     1.834    1.834   -0.000

[cc.qpm.app.IVError.main()] INFO cc.qpm.app.IVError - data: 20240913 14:05:09 SPY 20240920 559 P   3.458 0.140 562.170
    value [ib w/ ib iv, ql w/ ib iv]                      3.458    3.422   -0.036
    iv [ib model iv, ql iv from ib model value]           0.140    0.141    0.001
    value [ib model, ql value from ql iv of ib value]     3.458    3.458   -0.000

[cc.qpm.app.IVError.main()] INFO cc.qpm.app.IVError - data: 20240913 14:05:13 SPY 20240920 559 P   3.463 0.140 562.160
    value [ib w/ ib iv, ql w/ ib iv]                      3.463    3.427   -0.036
    iv [ib model iv, ql iv from ib model value]           0.140    0.141    0.001
    value [ib model, ql value from ql iv of ib value]     3.463    3.463    0.000

[cc.qpm.app.IVError.main()] INFO cc.qpm.app.IVError - data: 20240913 14:05:15 SPY 20240920 559 P   3.465 0.140 562.155
    value [ib w/ ib iv, ql w/ ib iv]                      3.465    3.429   -0.036
    iv [ib model iv, ql iv from ib model value]           0.140    0.141    0.001
    value [ib model, ql value from ql iv of ib value]     3.465    3.465    0.000

[cc.qpm.app.IVError.main()] INFO cc.qpm.app.IVError - data: 20240913 14:05:16 SPY 20240920 559 P   3.463 0.140 562.160
    value [ib w/ ib iv, ql w/ ib iv]                      3.463    3.427   -0.036
    iv [ib model iv, ql iv from ib model value]           0.140    0.141    0.001
    value [ib model, ql value from ql iv of ib value]     3.463    3.463    0.000

[cc.qpm.app.IVError.main()] INFO cc.qpm.app.IVError - data: 20240913 14:05:18 SPY 20240920 559 P   3.472 0.140 562.140
    value [ib w/ ib iv, ql w/ ib iv]                      3.472    3.435   -0.036
    iv [ib model iv, ql iv from ib model value]           0.140    0.141    0.001
    value [ib model, ql value from ql iv of ib value]     3.472    3.472    0.000

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  2.692 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2024-09-16T13:13:32-04:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

